# Image map re-sizing

Tags: imagemap

I have been looking to dynamically scale a image map with coordinates to a div, so when  re-sizing a window occurs the map and all coordinates are scaled accordingly.
any suggestions on how to do this?

i think this may work 
http://blog.outsharked.com/p/image-map-resizer.html

but with the alternate option of :enter a bounding area and the map will be clipped to within that area.

my question then is how do i establish a bounding area, will it scale dynamically to that whole area?

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin works great for scaling and rescaling image maps on the fly. You can call this once, and it will take care of all image maps on the page. It will even rescale an image map if something happens that changes an image's dimensions.

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps.

If you weren't just using the div to solve the image map scaling problem, you could put a blank image (a completely transparent .gif or .png) in your div with the image map applied to it and set its width and height to 100%.

Comment: using the image map plugin, the image is resizing as it should although i cant get the coordinates to do the same. Only difference between my code and the other is i chose rect instead of poly for the image map coords.